# SpringBoot security allow endpoints to be public and have ip access restriction

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Have build a rest service in Springboot that has 2 endpoints.

```
/status
/api
```

What I want is to protect all requests with AD Auth. And only allow "/status/**" too be public but with IP restrictions.

I have tried this but it wont work.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            // Disabled csrf since we currently don't have applications with UI depending on session or cookies.
            .csrf().disable()
            // Enable Cors, by using Corsfilter below
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/status/**").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/status/**").access(createHasIpRangeExpression())
            // Needed for verify if user is part of the AD-groups are extracted via Waffle
            .anyRequest()
            .hasAnyAuthority(allowedAuthorities)
            .and()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(userToAccessLogFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}


    private String createHasIpRangeExpression() {
    String ipRanges = allowedIps;
    List<String> validIps = Arrays.asList(ipRanges.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    String hasIpRangeAccessExpresion = validIps.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("') or hasIpAddress('", "hasIpAddress('", "')"));
    return hasIpRangeAccessExpresion;
}
```

I have also tried to remove

```
.antMatchers("/status/**").anonymous()
```

When i removed this line the IP restrictions works but i still need to be in the AD group to access the endpoint.

EDIT 2:
What i have tried as commented below but still need to auth into AD before accessing /status

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            // Disabled csrf since we currently don't have applications with UI depending on session or cookies.
            .csrf().disable()
            // Enable Cors, by using Corsfilter below
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/status", "/status/**").access("permitAll and (" +createHasIpRangeExpression() + ")")
            .anyRequest()
            .hasAnyAuthority(allowedAuthorities)
            .and()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(userToAccessLogFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Comment: Why `/status` and `/status/**`? Why is one only ip restricted and the other not? What is the difference? From your description it looks like you want `/status/**` to only have an IP range restriction.

Comment: @M.Deinum my fault. what i want is /status/** to be public and ip restricted. i will correct my question. thanks

Comment: Your current config won't work, as ou now have 2 expressions for 1 URL pattern. That will fail. Instead you need to do something like `access=("permitAll and hasIpAddress('....");`. You need a single expression. Also is `/status` only available to non logged in or to everyone?

Comment: @M.Deinum /status to everyone even if you are logged in.

Comment: The configuration Deinum suggested is correct, you have to add the permitAll to the expression the config will look something like this `.antMatchers("/status/**").access("permitAll and " +createHasIpRangeExpression())` and remove `.antMatchers("/status/**").anonymous()`

Comment: @A.Caldarigi ok i tried it but i still need to log in to access /status . It seems that "            .anyRequest()
            .hasAnyAuthority(allowedAuthorities)" comes first

Comment: `/status/**` doesn't match `/status`... Write something like `antMatchers("/status", "/status/**")` to include both url patterns. Also your expression should read `permitAll and (" + createHasIpRangeExpression() + ")");` else the ands and ors wouldn't match up.

Comment: @M.Deinum is still doesnt work. I updated my questions with your suggesion. Still need to log in before accessing /status

Comment: see if `createHasIpRangeExpression` returns a correct expression, and see if all ip are correct.

Comment: @A.Caldarigi i have it prePostEnabled = true. I even tried "access("permitAll and hasIpAddress('10.10.1.12')")" but when i removed the "hasIpAddress" then /status is public. but as soon as i add hasIpAddress then i need to auth with AD before accessing the path

Comment: i see you have some filters, can you check from the HttpServletRequest present in the filter if the ip its the same?(Just trigger the filter in someway)

Comment: @A.Caldarigi Ip address is the same. I get the login dialog before accessing the url path. only that is weird. but only when adding "hasIpAddress" maybe this combination doesnt work?

Comment: mmh, try with hasIpAddress only

Comment: @A.Caldarigi if i use HasIpAddress only i still need to log in.

Comment: are you calling your server via localhost or 127.0.0.1 ? @Tan

Comment: If you are calling your server via localhost or 127.0.0.1, your requests will be shown to the server as if they come from localhost or 127.0.0.1, if you instead call your server via the IP provided from your DHCP server, the server will see your request coming from your Ip like(10.10.1.12).

Comment: @A.Caldarigi Every time im testing im using another client that browse into my rest service. so the ip is fine. It seems like when using hasIPAddress forces the AD restriction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235965/discussion-between-a-caldarigi-and-tan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
                .antMatchers("/status", "/status/**").access(createHasIpRangeExpression()) //hasIpAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") or hasIpAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")...
```

There's no need for permitAll, bacause if the ip Matches you can proced, otherwise you will be redirected to the login.

Remember

> If you are calling your server via localhost or 127.0.0.1, your requests will be shown to the server as if they come from localhost or 127.0.0.1, if you instead call your server via the IP provided from your DHCP server, the server will see your request coming from your Ip like(10.10.1.12).

So if you are getting errors, always check which is the remote ip of the made request.
In the current case if the Ip doesn't match the given ones, you will be redirected to the login page.

At the end the config will result something like this.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            // Disabled csrf since we currently don't have applications with UI depending on session or cookies.
            .csrf().disable()
            // Enable Cors, by using Corsfilter below
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/status", "/status/**").access(createHasIpRangeExpression())
            .anyRequest()
            .hasAnyAuthority(allowedAuthorities)
            .and()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(userToAccessLogFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```